# I get an error : "The import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE" can not be resolved in Android

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I am trying to use a web service from my Android App using ksoap and I downloaded `ksoap2-android-assembly-2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.

I kept this .jar file in the lib folder.

I get errors in import statements:

```
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
```

What am I missing?

Can anybody please help me solve this issue?

Comment: Please clean your project and try again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Right Click Your Project
- Go to Properties
- Find below part
- Click Add JARs
- Choose your Jar from your lib folder
- And it's OK!

[image: Click ADD JAR AND HERE]

**EDIT :**

Also be sure your folder hierarchy looks like this :

[image]

And here's stable [ksoap-2 library jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.4/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar).

Comment: I have already done this. But I can see from your screen-shot that the ksoap version that I am using and you are using is different.. Could it be one of the reasons..??

Comment: I don't think so but maybe your library is damaged. You can download mine here : https://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/files/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar. Also see my answer again please.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing file.. I could get rid of all the errors. 
##maybe your library is damaged## This seems to be most obvious reason for my isseus..

Thanks Again..

Comment: Your welcome. Please accept as an asnwer if it helped you to solve.